# Embedded Payment return url shown in iframe

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to implement adaptive payments as embedded payment with lightbox.

It works fine until a user makes a payment, but after user completes the payment 
page specified by `return url` gets loaded within the iframe.
I'm expecting it to be loaded in the window NOT in the iframe.
Following is the code that I have. Am I missing something?

**Environment**
Java(play framework)
PayPal_Platform_Java_SDK_N

**Expected Page Transfer Scenario**
PageA - ("pay with paypal" button click)
    → paypal dialog - ("close" button click)
    → PageB

**PageA.html**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame">
  <dl>
    <dt></dt>
    <dd>
      <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
      <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-KEY">
      <input type="submit" id="paypalSubmitBtn" value="Pay with paypal" />
    </dd>
  </dl>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var dgFlow;
  $(function(){
    dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'paypalSubmitBtn' });
  }); 
</script>
```

**PageB.html**

```
<p>Thank you for your payment!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleEmbeddedFlow() {
    if (top && top.opener && top.opener.top) {
      top.opener.top.dgFlow.closeFlow();
    }
    else{
      top.dgFlow.closeFlow();
    }
    top.close();
  }

  jQuery.event.add(window, "load", function(){
    alert("window.load");
    handleEmbeddedFlow();
  });
</script>
```

I also noticed that `dgFlow` can not be resolved in else case's `top.dgFlow.closeFlow();`  in PageB.html.

Comment: I'm just interested if other developers who try the same thing have succeeded this....

Comment: okay, got the lightbox working, but as mentioned the mini browser will most likely display for 90% of users because who actually remains logged into PayPal?  I am getting the same result as you, the returnUrl and cancelUrls appear in the IFrame. Very annoying. Did you find a fix for this? Is it possible to get the url of the IFrame before closing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to detect if the page is running in an iframe, and if so redirect to the page directly.

How to detect: 
[How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

How to redirect:
[Redirect the parent page from IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092275/redirect-the-parent-page-from-iframe)