# Loading the login page outside of IFRAMES when the authentication ticket/cookie expires/times out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

The master page of my ASP.NET MVC application has two IFRAME's.

1) A horizontal IFRAME at the top that displays the application logo, sign out link, etc.

2) The rest of the screen area below the top bar is occupied by the second IFRAME, in which all the views are loaded.

After the authentication times out, ASP.NET automatically redirects the user to the login page. However, because the views run in the IFRAME below, after the time out, when ASP.NET redirects the user to the login page appears, the login page now appears in the IFRAME below with the top IFRAME still appearing showing the user to be still signed in.

I want that when the user is redirected to the login page on authentication cookie time-out, the login page must appear without any IFRAMEs in the main window of the browser.

How do I do this?

I suspect I'll need to override some HttpModule implementation written by Microsoft that is responsible for this default behavior. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to have a `Redirect` instruct the browser to redirect to a new page. The redirect will always happen within the `iframe`.

You could change the "timeout" page:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <authentication mode="Forms">
              <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Timeout" timeout="1" />
         </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And then in the timeout page you will need to have a link like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.top.location.href='/Account/LogOn'">Login Again</a>
```

References:

[Redirect the parent page from IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092275/redirect-the-parent-page-from-iframe)

[How to redirect to logon page when session State time out is completed in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873398/how-to-redirect-to-logon-page-when-session-state-time-out-is-completed-in-asp-ne)

**Note:** You could avaoid this by not using IFRAMES. They are generally frowned upon and you could instead use a shared view that contains all your shared header HTML.

Comment: Ah brilliant! Food for thought. Thank you much.

Comment: Regarding your comment about avoiding IFRAMES, I couldn't agree with you more. I hate IFRAMES. But there are times when you don't have much say in business decisions, esp. when they encroach upon technical decisions. You have to follow the money bag.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for. I was right in assuming that I'd have to handle some event in the `HttpApplication` class or through an `HttpModule`.

It so happens that the request is authenticated by ASP.NET in the `HttpApplication` class' `Authenticate` event.

If I provide a handler for that, I can override the default logic and do whatever I want there.

In my case, I would create a javascript that sets the `top.href = "~/Login/Index"`. I would then write this script to the response buffer and then flush the buffer so that nothing else gets written on it.